# Celery can't find .settings

Tags: python, django, docker, redis, celery

I installed redis and celery, set everything up, I run celery in terminal - everything is ok:

```
(venv) Air-Evgeny:gunter_site evgenybar$ celery -A gunter_site worker -l info
 
 -------------- celery@Air-Evgeny.Dlink v5.2.7 (dawn-chorus)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- macOS-13.0.1-x86_64-i386-64bit 2023-01-02 18:35:10
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         gunter_site:0x106d5a3a0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0
- ** ---------- .> results:     
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
                

[tasks]
  . gunter_site.celery.debug_task
```

Next, through the Python console, I try to run debug_task.delay() from celery.py to check that everything is working fine:

`>>> from gunter_site.gunter_site.celery import debug_task`

^Everything is ok at this stage

`>>> debug_task.delay()`

^Here I get a long list of problems that end with:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gunter_site.settings'`

Redis launched in docker: `docker run -p 6379:6379 --name redis-celery -d redis`
Redis work:

```
evgenybar@Air-Evgeny ~ % docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS       PORTS                    NAMES
01d5f6356e0f   redis     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago   Up 2 hours   0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp   redis-celery
```

I have already tried to create a test project with an older version of django, start redis explicitly by specifying the port: `docker run -p 127.0.0.1:16379:6379 --name redis-celery -d redis`, tried to find a solution on google and on youtube but no one seems to have the same problem.

Comment: This should be fixed either by setting PYTHONPATH or running the Celery worker in the right directory. This is a common error that people complain about every now and then...